# How to prevent merging of excluded files?

Tags: git

Let's say I have file `secret_config` in `.git/info/exclude`. My colleague, who doesn't know about this file, thinks file with such name might look shiny in his repository, so he creates, commits and pushes it. I, in good mood, want to `pull`, as every morning, but git starts to yell at me:

> error: Untracked working tree file 'secret_config' would be
>   overwritten by merge.  Aborting

How to tell git to stop yelling at me? Is it possible to tell him to completely ignore this file even while pulling or fetching/merging?

**Edit:**

When I temporarily create `.gitignore` and put `secret_config` to it, it, at least, allows me to pull properly. I need to emulate this functionality somehow.

Comment: Here's [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another/4044387#4044387) post that may be relevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly a solution, but there's possibility to change merging strategy, so file always keeps your local version. You just need to create file `.gitattributes` in the same directory as file you want to prevent merging and put `name_of_file merge=ours` in it. Downside is, you have to commit this file, so it feels like polluting repository with junk that no one but you needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can share your list of ignored files via `.gitignore`, e.g.

```
$ mv .git/info/exclude .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -v "Add ignored file list"
$ git push
```

Next time he pulls he will inherit your list of ignored files. This doesn't fix the history of files he already committed in his repository though.

Comment: I think he still wants that file tracked though.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This would ignore the file through whole repository.