# Git: Only push private config file to test repository and not to github?

Tags: git, github, config

I have a Rails app with a `config/my_private_data.yml` file. I would like to push the entire app both to my test server and to github.

However, when I push to the test server, I want to include the private file. When I push to github, I don't want to include the private file. What is the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: How private? If it's a massive desaster if the file becomes public, don't include it at all (use a `config/private_data.yml.template` with default values). Chances are you, or someone makes a mistake and you have the data on github or somewhere else where you never thought of now.

Comment: Not particularly private, but not something that I want to share. I wouldn't post my nuclear codes to github or even put them in my app.

Comment: this here should be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up two branches. `master` and `secret`. You can then add and commit the `config/my_private_data.yml` in the `secret` branch which you can then push into the master branch at the testserver.

```
touch config/my_private_data.yml
git checkout -b secret
git add config/my_private_data.yml
git commit -m 'Commited secret file'
git push testserver_repo_url secret
git checkout master
git push repo_on_github master
```

Then do a `git checkout secret; git rebase master` if you have new commits on master.
Don't commit on `secret` and if you do, do a cherry pick of that commit.

---

Certainly, not all is good with this approach. From what I can think now, you could inadvertently push the secret branch to github. Also, you can't really work in `master` if you need the `my_private_data.yml`-file (you can do a checkout of that file from the secret branch though).

Comment: Is there a better way to approach this? My use case is that I want to push to github for backup but push to my test server for testing and the app won't load without the private file.

Comment: I guess the next question would be whether the opposite is possible -- say, I work on master, which includes the secret file, and then I push a branch of master that doesn't have the secret file to github. Would there be a quick way and/or script to always branch master, delete all instances of the secret file, and then push the branch to github?

Comment: @Clay In theory you can use hooks (google git hooks) but there is no way to delete all instances of the secret file from git (because you can't change the git history).

Comment: You can have a branch `public` and a `private` branch. (There is nothing special about that `master` branch, it's just a name.) If you want you can pretend that `private` is called master, and only push the public branch. Whereas, in my answer the master branch is the public one but really that's just the name I gave it.