# Is it possible to associate untracked & ignored files with a specific branch?

Tags: git, windows-7

I have a git repository with 2 branches. My .gitignore specifies "*.dll" as one of the patterns.

1. When in `branch1`, I copy-paste `test.dll` into the root folder.
2. Then I switch to branch #2 using `git checkout branch2`.

My `branch2` shows the newly added `test.dll`. I don't want it to show up in `branch2`. Is it possible to associate this untracked and ignored file with `branch1`, so that it will only show up when I `git checkout branch1`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be easily done, and the solution proposed in "[Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044387/6309)" doesn't work.

You can [ignore it temporarily](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html)

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged README.textile
```

But that is a local setting (it wouldn't be propagated by a `push` like a `.gitignore` file would)

Comment: Thank you, VonC. I imagine that your solution will work, however it will require that I add "test.dll" to index. This seems like a major hack, since that file is actually part of .gitignore. My take away from your answer is that I simply can't achieve what I want and should simply accept that it's how git works - anything that isn't tracked will not belong to any specific branch. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @niaher "anything that isn't tracked will not belong to any specific branch" that the (current) idea, but it might evolve if someone submit a patch for Git.