# git ignore on one branch but not on another

Tags: git, github

There's a repository that's not mine on github. I cloned it so now I have a copy of it in my github account and I have a copy of that repo on my computer. I made a branch that has its own directory and a whole lot of files which I then committed to that branch, call it apple. When I switch back to the master branch I notice in status that the directory and all the files in it that I committed to on apple show up in the status. So now I have a hundred or so files that every time I switch over to master are visible.

My question is how can I make it so that when I switch back over to master those files I have in the apple branch are ignored? I'm sure I could amend the .gitignore in master but that would be changing the project's .gitignore.

Thanks


**EDIT:** Commenters have pointed out that if the files were committed in another branch they should not show up when I switch branches and this is correct. After working with everyone who helped me here what I discovered had happened was one of the subdirectories in the directory I created on the apple branch had its own .gitignore that ignored a lot files. That .gitignore was committed in the apple branch and when I switched branches (for example to the master branch) that directory specific .gitignore disappeared and all the files that were originally ignored on the apple branch showed up in any other branch in git-gui as being untracked. So I had a whole lot of files that I thought were committed on the apple branch but actually weren't. Sorry for the confusion! I will be marking Ryan Stewart's answer as correct.

Comment: google and stack could do the work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another

Comment: The referenced link modifies .gitignore, which the question rules out because "that would be changing the project's .gitignore."

Comment: If the files were committed in another branch, they should not show up when you switch to a branch where they are not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly added new files and committed them on branch apple, then switched back to master, which doesn't contain apple in its history, then those new files won't show up. Something about your description of the problem doesn't make sense.

Perhaps you don't realize that in git, you must `git add` files before you `git commit` them (unless you specifically use `git commit <files>`)? Specifically, if you added directory banana on branch apple, then you could do the following:

```
git add banana
git commit -m "added the banana feature"
git checkout master
```

And then you'd be in the master branch, and there'd be no banana. After a `git checkout apple`, banana would be back again because it exists in that branch.

Comment: If I switch back to master, the directory that I committed in apple is listed as an untracked directory

Comment: Then at least something in that directory isn't committed.

Comment: A `git status -u` will show you a full list of all uncommitted files instead of just top-level directories that are untracked.

Comment: I'm using the git-gui on windows and it shows every file in the directory for unstaged changes. It makes it difficult for me to find the changes I actually want when I'm on master.

Comment: You originally said "untracked". That's not the same as "unstaged". I still think that you just haven't committed the files in the branch. Try following my instructions above and looking at the results.

Comment: yeah I did some investigating and you are correct. I've updated my original post and marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 6):

You can set your own 'global ignore' file as such:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

You then populate `~/.gitignore_global` as you please. Additionally you can edit

```
.git/info/exclude
```

just like `.gitignore` but it will only apply to that .git repository.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is a way I can ignore that directory in any branch outside of the one where it's relevant. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The 'apple' stuff shouldn't be visible on the master branch.  See Ryan Stewart's answer above.

Comment: Perfect, adding files to .git/info/exclude worked for me.