# How to track a file only in particular branch in Git

Tags: git, github, git-branch

there is a file local_settings.py of a Github repo which is ignored in .gitignore

There is a production branch locally on my system.. We rebase as soon as there are updates in master. However, this branch needs to track local_settings.py to push into server!!

If I remove this file in production-branch/.gitignore, and commit, local_settings.py goes into this branch and disappears in all other branches disabling to run project locally on my system. Oops..

How to fix it? any better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this in my projects is by having a set of three files: `dev_settings.py`, `staging_settings.py`, and `prod_settings.py`, all of which are versioned (there's also `dev_settings_local.py` style unversioned config so each developer can override defaults).

An environment variable or symlink selects which configuration will be used on each machine.

Now your production configuration is versioned, which means you don't have to try to gitignore files only in certain situations.

Comment: when ever I merge master or rebase, conflict arises in merging.