# git branch for deploy

Tags: git, deployment, branch

I created this repo as a sample:
https://github.com/neves/deploy-workflow

I do my work on "master" and use the "deploy" branch for deploying to server.
On master branch, I don't want to track the assets/vendor/*, so I ignore them.

On deploy branch I add them, because they need exist for deploy.
All working till here.

The problem is that when I checkout back to master, the ignored content inside assets/vendor/ folder are deleted.

How can I stop that? Is there a better way to keep a separated branch for deploying with some different files in?

Comment: Why do you not want those files in your master branch if they are needed there?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a "excludefile" directive just for the `master` branch (in order to ignore `assets/vendor/*`), while *not* ignoring that directory in the `deploy` branch.

See "[Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044387/6309)"

```
cd .git/
$ touch info/exclude_from_master
$ echo "assets/vendor/" > info/exclude_from_master

git config core.excludesfile +info/exclude
git config branch.master.excludesfile +info/exclude_from_master
```

Comment: I've tried this before. To be sure, I repeat your exact same code and didn't work either.
git version 1.8.2.3

Comment: excludesfile = +info/exclude_from_master doesn't work on branch or even on core. But if I add assets/vendor/ to info/exclude, it works, but for all branchs.

Comment: @user2529613 ok, I thought it was worth mentioning. I will test it later.