# How to solve this git merge issue with deleted files?

Tags: git

This is what I want to do:
I have 2 branches: dev and prod
in dev I have a folder with .less files:

styles/less/myfile.less

So in dev I edit my styles by editing myfile.less, the .css file is automatically updated in styles/css/myfile.css

In prod branch I don't need to keep the /less/myfile.less or even the /less/ folder
So in prod branch I deleted it using 
git rm styles/css/myfile.less
git commit -m "Deleted .less file"

Then:
git checkout dev

Done some more work in myfile.less
added and committed it to dev

Them:
git checkout prod
git merge dev

Now I see CONFLICT message, something like CONFLICT (modify/delete): styles/less/myfile.less deleted in HEAD and modified in dev. Version dev of styles/less/myfile.less left in tree.

This is not unexpected but what I really want to do is to NOT have myfile.less in prod and have myfile.less in dev and when I merge dev into prod I want git to automatically use "ours" merge strategy to accept that file is deleted so I don't have to resolve this conflict every time I merge dev into prod

Is this possible at all? Can this be done with some entry in .gitattributes file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another)

Comment: I read that question and tried the solution but it did not help. I'm still getting conflict messages every time I merge dev into prod because prod has file deleted but in dev this file was modified. I think ignoring styles/less/myfile.less in prod branch will only work in I actually have that file in prod but since I don't have it in prod the solution does not work. I also tried to add the whole styles/less/ directory to ignore but that also did not work.

Comment: Actually, read his question and his initial setup. It sounds like what he initially has is what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: hey @Dmitri, have you find a solution to your problem? I am going through the same issue.