# Excluding a file from branches in git?

Tags: git, github, branch, gitignore

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a file be on a "dev" branch, but not on a "master" branch. I've been looking at [this](http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/63560840467/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches-update) but am having a bit of trouble understanding it. What I want to do is keep a single file to one branch exclusively. Everything I'm reading with `.gitignore` and `excludefiles` seems more about excluding the files from the repository in general instead of from a specific branch.

So, would the method in the link work for excluding a file from specific branches? Or is there another way to do it?

(I'm new to using git, and don't entirely understand the remote section at the end)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another)

Comment: @nwinkler that's actually the link that I referenced in my post. I guess I'm looking for a clearer explanation of it.