# Git - Include file in single branch, instead of excluding from many

Tags: git, github

Asked a similar question about a week ago but didn't get a response. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another), I was able to hide my file from the master branch. However, I would prefer to only include the file in one branch, instead of excluding multiple branches.

Is there a way to do that so I don't have to add in a new branch each time one is created?

Comment: You obviously could add a pattern which ignores the file for each branch and add if forcefully to the branch in question. But the file will be available on another branch as soon as you merged in the branch in question. May I ask why you want to do this? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I know, but that's what we're trying to avoid. I'd rather have something that is just in the single branch that keeps it only there and that doesn't have to be edited every time a new branch is created.

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see anything so I figured I'd ask. Thanks!