# Git excludesfile for a branch

Tags: git, gitignore, git-config

I want to ignore certain files within a branch without having to rely on a tracked `.gitignore` file that will be overwritten during merges with other branches.

I’ve closely followed [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742) along with [the linked blog post](http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/1423976659/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches), but my repo doesn’t seem to be recognizing the specified `excludesfile` in my `.git/config`. The Git documentation ([`git-config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#Syntax), [`gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)) doesn’t seem to show how to specify and address an excludes file for a specific branch.

My `.git/config` looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
        excludesfile = +/info/exclude

[branch "myspecialbranch"]
        excludesfile = +/info/exclude_specialbranch
```

My `.git/info/exclude` file looks like this (by default, I didn’t touch it):

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
.DS_Store
```

I don’t have a `.gitignore` file in my “specialbranch”.

If I try to ignore a file like `info.php`, my `.git/info/exclude_specialbranch` file looks like this:

```
info.php
```

… but it doesn’t ignore the file.

If I run `git status --ignored`, it only lists the `.DS_Store` file from the default `exclude` file.

However, if I add `info.php` to my `.git/info/exclude` file:

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
.DS_Store
info.php
```

it ignores the file perfectly.

Note that it still works without the line `excludesfile = +/info/exclude` under `[core]` in `.git/config`. Git seems to know where the system-wide `exclude` is without me having to tell it.

I have a feeling that `.git/config` isn’t recognizing the address of my custom excludes file:

```
excludesfile = +/info/exclude_specialbranch
```

… most likely because of the use of `+` to describe the location of the `.git` directory.

What’s the correct method for addressing custom exclude files in the (more recent) versions of Git?

I’m running OSX 10.9.5 and Git version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Git does not support per-branch excludes files

You’re trying to achieve something that Git does not support. The [blog post](http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/1423976659/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches) is the original source of this hoax that [the Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044387/2157640) only parroted. As noted in comments under that answer, even the original blog post contains a discussion that brings out that the solution does not work and it links to a [newer blog post](http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/63560840467/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches-update) that mentions that even the author is unable to reproduce the behavior.

Why it does not work? If you read [`man gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and [`man git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), you’ll find just `core.excludesfile` referenced. No `branch.<name>.excludesfile` there. The `core.excludesfile` is meant to enable you to exclude e.g. Vim .swp files or other temporary stuff your software uses.

> `core.excludesfile`
>
> In addition to `.gitignore` (per-directory) and `.git/info/exclude`, Git looks into this file for patterns of files which are not meant to be tracked. "`~/`" is expanded to the value of `$HOME` and "`~user/`" to the specified user’s home directory. Its default value is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` is used instead. See [gitignore(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

## Workaround

I believe that the best approximation of a per-branch excludes file is achieved using the [post-checkout hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) and that rewrites the contents of `.gitignore` in the working tree.<sup>*</sup>

Each branch would have e.g. a `.gitignores` directory with files named after the corresponding branches. Then there would be a `.gitignores/__default` file that would be used by default. The `.gitignore` would be excluded by all the excludes files and would be created by the post-checkout hook as a copy of the corresponding file in `.gitignores`.

If you don’t want to track the excludes files, you may do the same with `.git/info/exclude` file as a copy of `.git/info/excludes/__default` etc.

<sup>*</sup>: *Side note: I used to recommend making .gitignore a symlink updated by the hook to point to the right content, but [.gitignore cannot be symlink since Git v2.32.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.32.0.txt). Now, when editing the .gitignore, the changes are lost when switching branches, instead of being made to the branch's custom excludes file.*

Comment: If you want more info on the work-around, feel free to ping me via @Palec in the comments here.

Comment: ha thanks - i just finished reading the entire http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config (!) and was wondering why i didn't see a branch.excludesfile - i'll check out your work-around.

Comment: I checked the history of git-config and gitignore manpages and they never mentioned `branch.<name>.excludesfile`.

Comment: ok thanks - so it looks like it was _never_ possible...  good to know.

Comment: Actually, I’m not 100% sure yet that it never worked. I’m just sure it was never documented. What puzzles me it the high number of upvotes on the answer you tried to follow. I downvoted it, upvoted the comment that says it doesn’t work, and I recommend anyone who reads this to do the same.

Comment: `git stash -u -a` seems to be a usable workaround for me, but it's tedious when the directories to ignore contain some gigabytes.

Comment: I need the same functionality, but for separate `changelog-[branch].log`. @Palec, I have never created a post-checkout hook. And from your answer it is not clear if the process you propose, is automated by `git` itself or we need to use a script (like in the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696220/3408342))? I need this to be automated in both Linux and Windows (as we used both of these OSes for development).

Comment: Hooks are separate executables or scripts, Git does not create them. I'll probably never write such a script as I don't need that functionality and it's not trivial. If you encounter any issues with implementing it yourself and don't find an answer, you may post a new question about it. @tukusejssirs

Comment: Someone wrote this post-checkout hook: https://gist.github.com/wizioo/c89847c7894ede628071

I have not tried this myself.

Comment: @Palec About the high number of upvotes - I upvoted it as it seemed like a simple and easy-to-understand solution to my problem - then when I tried to remove my upvote, I was told that my vote was locked in. Maybe clicking on the "up" arrow a second time doesn't remove the vote, and I'm not the only one who tried to un-upvote.

Comment: I think the proposed workaround doesn't work any more. After 2.32, git no longer allows .gitignore to be a symlink (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.32.0.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @Jasancos! Updated my answer so that the workaround works even after the change. By using a copy instead of a symlink, it loses some of the convenience, but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script I wrote to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      

# This is designed to allow per-branch un-ignoring of certain files.
# Use case: Compiled CSS files on master to push to server.
# A special .gitignore file will be present on master at
# {$gitignorePath}/{$disabledMasterGitignoreName} and that file should 
# enable the css files using the ! flag. @https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

# When the branch specified by script parameters
# is checked out, {$gitignorePath}/{$disabledMasterGitignoreName} is 
# copied to .gitignore. 
# On other branches this gitignore file is named $disabledMasterGitignoreName, versioned,
# and {$gitignorePath}.gitignore will be deleted. Note, you must ignore 
# {$gitignorePath}.gitignore from your main .gitignore file
#
# To enable put this file in your path and call this script
# in .git/hooks/post-checkout with pass a list of single-space-separated branches that
# will enable the branch-specific .gitignore.

# One caveat is that you can only merge into the branch containing the .gitignore
# file. Otherwise you'll end up re-committing the files. This is fine if you are
# using gitflow and `master` contains your special .gitigore using the ! syntax
# that is un-ignoring files.
#
# Background: @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579546/git-excludesfile-for-a-branch

set -e                                                                           

gitignorePath='docroot/sites/all/themes'
disabledMasterGitignoreName='.gitignore_master--disabled'
#branchWithGitignoreEnabled='master'

branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

gitignoreRoot="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/${gitignorePath}"

if [ -f "${gitignorePath}/.gitignore" ]
then
    masterGitignoreExists=true
fi

if [ -f "${gitignorePath}/${disabledMasterGitignoreName}" ]
then
    disabledMasterGitignoreExists=true
fi

IFS=' ' read -a params <<< "$@"

if [[ " ${params[@]} " =~ " ${branch} " ]]
then
  if [ $disabledMasterGitignoreExists ]
  then
    cp -f "${gitignoreRoot}/${disabledMasterGitignoreName}" "${gitignoreRoot}/.gitignore"
    echo "Enabled ${gitignorePath}/.gitignore"
  fi
elif [ $masterGitignoreExists ]
then
    rm -f "${gitignorePath}/.gitignore"
    if [ masterGitignoreExists ]
    then
      echo "Disabled ${gitignorePath}/.gitignore"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Or see https://gist.github.com/wizioo/c89847c7894ede628071, as a comment to another answer recommended.