# In git, how to commit one file in a branch but ignore in all the other branches?

Tags: git, version-control

I have some secure key files which need to be committed only to the staging branch. But I need to ignore them in all the other branches.

In here [Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another) it shows how to **commit in one branch and ignore in another**. It didn't work for me. I want to **commit in one branch and ignore in all the others**. How can I do that?

Comment: The answer in your linked post is bogus: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29583813/1256452 (via http://stackoverflow.com/a/39280410/1256452).

Comment: If you have the file in `.gitignore` then you can still force add it in one branch `git add -f <filename>` and changes will be tracked for that branch only.

Comment: Thanks. But what if we merge that branch into another? Let's say we force add the file to branch `a`. Now I checkout to `b` and merge `a`. Will I get those files in `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the file listed in the .gitignore file in all other branches.

Then in the branch you want it tracked, add a `!` before the filename in the .gitignore file. Then manually add the file `git add <filename>` and it should now be tracked in this current branch but not in the others