# In git, how can one track files and commit them to only a specific remote, while keeping them available to other branches committing to other remotes?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-remote, git-config

## The problem in detail

I am making a game, and intend to open source the code but keep the assets private. My goal is to track the assets and game together in a private repository so that I can take advantage of version control with them, but only track the source code of the game in a public repo without committing the assets to that public repo. However, I cannot find a way to do this properly.

## Attempted solutions

I have two remote repositories on GitHub, one is public and the other is private. I have set up a master branch, which I intend to commit to the private repository, and a branch called master-public, which will commit to the public repository. In order to prevent accidentally committing assets to the public repository, I successfully implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579546/git-excludesfile-for-a-branch/29583813#29583813), and have my assets folder ignored on the branch master-public but not on the branch master. My intent was to make feature branches from master-public, merge feature branches with master-public, and then rebase master-public onto master. However, I cannot find a way to commit the assets to the private repo without either accidentally putting them into the public branches, or making them unavailable to all other branches. If I commit the assets folder to the master branch, they disappear from the directory when using checkout to switch to another branch. I have tried to mitigate this by adding it to a regular .gitignore, creating a branch out of the original master, then force adding the ignored asset and committing it; The file remains unavailable in other branches no matter how I attempt to make this work, despite trying the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291579/in-git-how-to-commit-one-file-in-a-branch-but-ignore-in-all-the-other-branches) as well.

Comment: If I had to do this, I would put the assets in a submodule.

Comment: Or as a simpler alternative to submodules, I'd use `git subtree`.

Comment: please elaborate! I don't know how to approach either of your suggestions, but would like to know more.

Comment: Yes: you can take a look at Atlassian's tutorial for example, https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree