# How to exclude a folder to be downloaded when hosting R package in github

Tags: r, devtools

My package is hosted in github, and user can install it through `devtools::install_github`.

Now I'm using pkgdown to generate documentation site, which created a 10M docs folder. Then I found `devtools::install_github` always download the whole master zip ball which become quite slow.

I tried to exclude the docs folder with these attempts:

- `.Rbuildignore`, turned out it's only about bundled package, while `install_github` is installing source package so it doesn't work.
- put package in `pkg` folder, put the generated `docs` folder out of `pkg` folder. However the whole master zip ball is always downloaded, even with `subdir = "pkg"` specified.
- put development in a branch, and to create a special package branch without docs folder. Merge two branch but let package branch exclude docs folder. I tried make .gitignore to be branch specific but it doesn't seem to work. [This seemed to be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579546/git-excludesfile-for-a-branch).
- My newest attempt is to create a separate repo solely for the website, just let `pkgdown` create the website in that folder like `build_site(path = "../docsite/docs")`. This should solve the problem and is simple and clean. The only imperfection is the website url will not be the usually pattern.

EDIT: with the latest version of `pkgdown`, there is no `path` parameter anymore, you need to specify it in the site configuration yaml, which works better (you don't need to specify it in every command).

Comment: Create a package, set up a (R package) repo at GitHub with drat, have users download from that (R package) repo.  Else split your source repo and exclude those files.  Clone will _always_ fetch them.

Comment: I took a brief look at `drat`. It seemed that greater control can be achieved with `drat`, though I'm afraid there will be a little bit learning cost for me, and I'm kind of spoiled by the `devtools` integration with rstudio for now. The 3 branches method (!) is working for me now. I may look at `drat` if some new problem arise and I have to control more details.

Comment: I took some time to try drat because of some github install issues. Pros and cons for my user case: pros: more control, user can use regular R install methods; cons: need to build package, update the repo manually. Of course you can make a script for it, just need several clicks for every release.

Comment: pkgdown to gh-pages branch

Comment: @JohnCoene, it's difficult to maintain two branches that hold different contents(one for code, one for doc site), when the doc branch actually need to be generated from code branch. And that was my 3rd attempt in post.

Comment: You might take a look at using Travis CI to automate some of this. I recently did this for the first time, starting off from [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/cd-package-docs-pkgdown-travis). My Travis config includes building the site, pushing the gh-pages branch, and deploying, so I don't have to worry about maintaining each branch.