# Can GIT track a file only in one branch but not on other?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-flow

I'm using GitFlow as git workflow. And I program for electronic microcontrollers.
While I'm on the development branch I don't need the compiled HEX file to be tracked or committed, I just need the code. But when I'm on the release or master branch, I do need the generated HEX file to be committed.
At the moment I'm "mentally" ignoring the HEX file, and only stage and commit to it when I need. But its kind of bothering, to have it there, always looking at you, asking "why all the other files, but not me"...
I feel kind of guilty, and I would prefer not to see it there unless I'm on the appropriate branch.
Any suggestion?

Comment: See this answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583813/7334245

Comment: It sounds like what you actually need is a release process.

Comment: Thanks @mikeskaife ive read your link already, although i was hoping that there was a workaround, as my case was simpler.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  I may need a release process, although im quite new to GIt, and more over to git-flow... is there any simple standardized git process to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a great way to do what you want.  I'd also suggest you recheck some assumptions, because when you say "...when I'm on [some branch] I do need the *generated* [anything]..." (emphasis added), that tells me you're probably not letting your source control system just be a source control system.

The problem with just saying "keep a different `.gitignore` on each branch" is, (1) it doesn't account for the fact that you'll regularly create branches that need to *not* ignore the HEX file, from a branch that needs to ignore the HEX file; and (2) one of the versions of `.gitignore` will be seen as a modification of the other, so it's possible for routine merges to silently carry that change into a branch that shouldn't get it.

You can use the structure provided by gitflow to make this more manageable, especially if you script the branch-and-merge activities around `release` branches.  You could just keep the HEX file in your `.gitignore`, but force-add it when staging the first commit on each `release` branch.  A few key points here:

1) All `.gitignore` does is say that if there are untracked files matching certain path patterns, those files should *by default* remain untracked.  Once a file *is* tracked, `.gitignore` has no further effect.

2) As used in point (!), "tracked" just means "in the index".  If a file is in commit `A` but not in commit `B`, then moving between commits `A` and `B` will generally update the index such that the file becomes tracked or untracked with each checkout, accordingly.  *But this does give rise to a problem...*

2a) If you're on `develop`, where the HEX file is `.gitignore`d, but you have an untracked HEX file in your work tree; and then you `git checkout master` (where `master` *does* have a HEX file), git will ignore your untracked HEX file and allow the checkout, causing your local version to be overwritten.  You will not be able to recover the HEX file.  Again, since you say the file is generated, this may not be a big deal; but it's something to keep in mind.

3) You can override the default behavior that keeps ignored files untracked by using the `-f` option of `git add`, as in

```
git add -f path/to/HEX/file
```

And if you follow the gitflow merging patterns, then you could simply do this force-add every time you create a `release` branch, overriding the ignore rule on `release` branches (and on `master`, which is composed of merges from `release` branches).  So far so good.

Of course, those merges to release do present a problem, because every time they will see the new HEX file as conflicting with the old one (since they were created independently as far as git can tell.  What you'd want, essentially, is the behavior of the default merge strategy's "theirs" option (take the version from the branch I'm merging in, if there's a conflict).  You may not want to use that option *except* for that one file; you could rig something up using `.gitattributes` maybe.

Also there is a problem if you ever do `hotfix` branches, because those are branched from `master` (so they'll have the HEX file) but you merge them to both `master` and `develop`.  So each hotfix has the risk of "leaking" the HEX file into the `develop` branch (after which you'd have to remove it again to get the ignore rule working).

If this seems like a lot of trouble, it is.  Again, in my opinion this is because you're working against the grain of a source control tool.  And to clarify, these problems are not peculiar to my proposed solution, but rather will arise with *any* solution to the problem as stated.  If git sees the file popping into existence on each release branch, but not present on develop or feature branches, then merges to master *will* conflict and hotfixes *will* risk copying the file to develop, no matter how exactly you got there.

Comment: Thank you for your throughout explanation. Its very clarifying, and explain most of the cases i was worried off... I think i will keep with my "mentally ignore" method of the HEX file, and only commit with it on the appropriate branch. The hassle of all the other method you mention are not worth it, also as you mention :)