# How to prevent ignored file in one branch to be detected in another branch in git?

Tags: git

Let say I have two branches in my Git repository.

1. `master`
2. `slave`

Now while in `master`, I created a file (holding some sensitive information)
called `apikey.env`. I added it to `.gitignore` file since I don't want to commit it. After that I committed the `.gitignore` with the new record.

Now, when I checkout to `slave` branch, I still find the `apikey.env` file there, about which, git says that it is **untracked**. If I delete the file, I gets removed from `master` branch as well.

So, what I want is that the file `apikey.env` should appear only in `master` branch but not in the `slave` branch, and I don't want to commit the file even in `master` branch. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Check solution at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another

Answer (score 1):

There is no one *best* way.  A simple way that works, though, is to add that path name to `.gitignore` in your other branch, and commit that `.gitignore` file there as well.

There's an incorrect assumption in your problem statement though:

> If I delete the [`apikey.env`] file, it gets removed from master branch as well.

The file should not *be* in (any commits on) `master` at all, and given how you phrased the text before this, it sounds like it *is* not in them.  So this file, while it is in your *work-tree*, is **not in any branch!**  (This phrasing is not very exact because we have not properly defined the word *branch*.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) for more about that.)

Comment: The simple way you mentioned works, but what if I have a lot of branches? Should I commit to `.gitignore` in those branches also? And by `branch`, I mean whatever Github portrays branches as.

Comment: @overflow_yoho_hoolala -  Consider that `.gitignore` is content just like any other file you commit.  So if your project must have a particular (function | class | page | whatever the units of code are for your type of project), and it must be available on all branches, you don't commit it on all branches; you commit it on the first branch, and as you branch from that first branch, the files are all there.  Ignore rules defined in `.gitignore` are the same; you only seem to have to commit the ignore rule twice because you'd already created a second branch before you introduced the rule.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yeah, the branches already branched out before I could commit the ignore rule in the first branch. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve it is to add it to an ignore file which is outside of your version control, and so won't change when you switch branches. The downside of this is that you have to replicate this non-versioned ignore file for each working directory / team member who gets this repo.

If it's just for this working directory, you can add to `.git/info/exclude` (same format as `.gitignore`).

If you want it to affect all workspaces on your local machine, you can add it to a `.gitignore` in your home dir and tell git to use that.

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

This will cause the file to be ignored by all git repos on your local machine.